# Can I get reputation on a bounty refunded?

Tags: support, reputation, bounty

I started a bounty on gaming.stackexchange.com on a question. If I dont award anyone the bounty I put on the question, will I get that reputation back?

Comment: I guess this is to prevent abuses. Bounties lead to more attention of your question, which correlates with more votes. So you could add a bounty just to get up voted and not award it. This way even if you add only bounties on your own questions you loose some points for a bit more attention.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you will not. The only way to get back a bounty after it's been placed is to have it returned to you by a mod, which is something a mod will only do in special circumstances. See the privileges page about [bounties](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/privileges/set-bounties) for more information.